# How to find minimum value from CSV file row in Python?

Tags: python, csv

I'm a beginner at Python and I am using it for my project.

I want to extract the minimum value from column4 of a CSV file and I am not sure how to.

I can print the whole of column[4] but am not sure how to print the minimum value (just one column) from column[4].

*CSV File: https://www.emcsg.com/marketdata/priceinformation 
I'm downloading the Uniform Singapore Energy Price & Demand Forecast for 9 Sep.*

Thank you in advance.

This is my current codes:

```
import csv
import operator

with open('sep.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    header = next(readCSV)
    data = []

for row in readCSV:
    Date = row[0]
    Time = row[1]
    Demand = row[2]
    RCL = row[3]
    USEP = row [4]
    EHEUR = row [5]
    LCP = row[6]
    Regulations = row[7]
    Primary = row[8]
    Secondary = row[9]
    Contingency = row[10]
    Last_Updated = row[11]

print header[4]
print row[4]
```

Comment: You've got some code; please provide a [mcve] in the question itself.

Comment: You changed row to column, so, I edited my answer. Also, be careful about indentation in Python.

Answer (score 0):

not sure how are you reading the values. however, you can add all the values to and list and then:

```
list = []
<loop to extract values>
list.insert(index, value)
min_value = min(list)
```

Note: index is the 'place' where the value get inserted.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT 2 :**
Solution for a column without pandas module:

```
with open("Realtime_Sep-2017.csv") as file:
    lines = file.read().split("\n")     #Read lines

num_list = []
for line in lines:
    try:
        item = line.split(",")[4][1:-1] #Choose 4th column and delete ""
        num_list.append(float(item))    #Try to parse 
    except:
        pass                            #If it can't parse, the string is not a number

print(max(num_list))                    #Prints maximum value
print(min(num_list))                    #Prints minimum value
```

Output:

```
81.92
79.83
```

**EDIT :**
Here is the solution for a column:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("Realtime_Sep-2017.csv")
row_count = df.shape[0]
column_list = []
for i in range(row_count):
    item = df.at[i, df.columns.values[4]]   #4th column
    column_list.append(float(item))         #parse float and append list

print(max(column_list))    #Prints maximum value
print(min(column_list))    #Prints minimum value
```

**BEFORE EDIT :**

(solution for a row)
Here is a simple code block:

```
with open("Realtime_Sep-2017.csv") as file:
    lines = file.read().split("\n") #Reading lines

num_list = []
line  = lines[3]    #Choosing 4th row.
for item in line.split(","):
    try:
        num_list.append(float(item[1:-1]))  #Try to parse
    except:
        pass    #If it can't parse, the string is not a number

print(max(num_list))    #Prints maximum value
print(min(num_list))    #Prints minimum value
```

Comment: So you're deleting the first character? Why? And why are you assuming that if the string can be parsed, it is a wanted value?

Comment: 1) I could choose not to delete first line, it can't be parsed to a float anyway. 2) We are trying to find minimum number in the list. If it can't be parsed to a float, it is not even a number. How can we choose this string as minimum value? If it could be parsed, I added it to the list. At the end, I called min() function, here is where I found the wanted number.

Comment: Thank you for the edit! I need to install something to 'import pandas as pd' right? Is there a way to do it without /pandas'?

Comment: @Autumn Yes, you need to install pandas module. I used pandas module to read csv file. It is better to use this module. But, if you don't want to use pandas module, you can use the code which I added with "EDIT 2".

Answer (score 0):

Your phrasing is a bit ambiguous. At first I thought you meant the minimum of the fourth row, but looking at the data you seem to be wanting the minimum of the fourth column (USEP($/MWh)). For that, (assuming that "Realtime_Sep-2017.csv" is the filename) you can do:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("Realtime_Sep-2017.csv")
print(min(df["USEP($/MWh)"])
```

Other options include  df.min()["USEP($/MWh)"], df.min()[4], and min(df.iloc[:,4])

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant column. I tried the codes out and it said 'invalid syntax' and a red box line appeared in the next line. Is it  because I'm using an older version of Python? (Python 2.7.13)

Comment: Isolate what syntax is invalid. Does df["USEP($/MWh)"] work? df.iloc[:,4]? df.min()?